# Filter duplicate get requests that Safari on iOS makes using NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express, safari

I'm logging the number of requests that various pages get to try to build up some analytics. I've noticed that when typing in the url into safari on my iPhone, once the site comes up as the suggested site and autofills the search bar, safari starts making multiple requests to preload the site.

Is there any way to identify whether a request is safari preloading the site or safari actually opening the site on the backend using NodeJS with Express?

I'm considering just looking at the IP address and not logging requests that come from the same IP in a certain timeframe but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Have you studied the preload requests in detail to see if there are any breadcrumbs in there (custom header, perhaps) that indicates it's a preload request?

Comment: Note, your proposed technique will undercount when/if the preload page is actually used.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes I know, this is less a concern though if they happen to reload in the 30 seconds I use for a cooldown I'll miss one log. I think this is the easiest method I've been able to get working so far.

Comment: I was thinking more about the case where user goes to page A which causes Safari to preload page B.  You don't count the load of page B because it appears to be too close in time to page A.  Then, anytime later, user clicks on link in page A and actually goes to page B.  That page is already cached so you don't get another request for it.  Thus, you don't count that page.